# In my mule application I need to access incoming message only once. which component I should use?

Tags: mule

I am getting incoming request through HTTP component and after processing saving that in to file. I have to process message only once and need to remove the duplicate message. I am not sure what I need to code/use for dropping duplicate message...
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use component Idempotent Message from the mule palette. That will be filter out any duplicate incoming message. That will serve your purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much pratikkumar for help.